# Serve * with express-static-gzip

Tags: express, gzip

I am trying to serve all routes to express with my dist folder.

```
app.use(expressStaticGzip('dist'));

app.get('*', (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(expressStaticGzip(path.join(`${__dirname}/dist/index.html`)));
});
```

When I run this code I got the error:

> Internal Server Error

If I use route by route it works:

```
app.use('/', expressStaticGzip('dist'));
```

But I need the all routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

I switched expressStaticGzip to compression and used express-history-api-fallback:

```
import fallback from 'express-history-api-fallback';
import express from 'express';
import compression from 'compression';

...

app.use(compression());

const root = `${__dirname}/dist`
app.use(express.static(root));
app.use(fallback('index.html', { root })) ;
```

And I changed my relative imports at index.html for absolute imports ('./' to '/')